# Angular APIs to run on server

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am maintaining a product that is already on production.

Our architecture is:
Angular connects to backend product to request and respond to calls. Angular service to call the backend product APIs.
The APIs respond with a token that is used in subsequent calls.

The problem is:
This token can be used to manipulate the call and let the user do more than expected from them. The backend product is a closed box. We can't write extra code in there to authenticate the call is legitim.

A solution I am thinking in:
Secure some parts of Angular to run on server.

I am not experienced Angular developer, non in my team is. So we are still investigating how to do that.

Any input will definitely help.

Answer (score 0):

There is the guard document in Angular.
Hope it can help some.
https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate